# Proof for sum of two reals

Tags: functions, real-numbers, alternative-proof

Let $$f(x), \ f(y),\ f(x+y),$$ for $\ x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$
Consider that: $$I) \ \ f(x)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$ my professor said that if $I)$ was true, then: $$f(x)=0 \implies f(y)= f(x+y)=0 \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},$$ I didn't see that implication so clearly so I questioned him. He proved that: $$f(y)=0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$$ Rather easily, but said that proving $$f(x+y)=0, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$ was not so trivial, and I should start **proving that all reals are a sum of other two**.

My question is:

**a) Is that the easiest approach or there's a more intuitive one?**

**b) How would one prove that the sum of two real numbers must be a real number?**

PS: This was an entry-level college course, so despite working with functions, reals were not well defined for us yet. Also, I studied polynomials and complex numbers in high school, despite not formally knowing what a function was. So don't just conclude this is trivial for anyone.

EDIT: Sorry for editing/reviving such an old thread, but this post had to be fixed, I didn't realize how much of a wreck my grammar was at that time.

Comment: Use "\mathbb{R}" instead of "\R"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a "how to think about it" type hint.

"$f(x) = 0 \ \ \ \forall x \in \Bbb R$" is completely independent of the fact that "$x$" is used to denote the input to $f$.

Think of what "$f(x) = 0 \ \ \ \forall x \in \Bbb R$" means in words:

> "This function $f$ gives me back $0$ no matter what real number I give to $f$."

To expand on that...

> "This function $f$ gives me back $0$ no matter what real number I give to $f$.  And it doesn't matter if I call that real number $x$, or $y$, or even $x+y$.  The point is that if I feed a real number to $f$, then $f$ always spits out $0$."

---

Note:  This is essentially the idea of a "dummy variable" which is commonly discussed when introducing integrals in calculus.  For example, $\int_0^1 2x \, dx = 1$.  And this is completely independent of the fact that $x$ is the variable of integration.  We could just easily say $\int_0^1 2y \, dy = 1$, because it doesn't matter what we call the variables.  What matters is that we use the variables correctly.

Comment: _This function f gives me back 0 no matter what real number I give to f, And it doesn't matter if I call that real number x, or y, or even x+y._ Well, for that conclusion x + y must belong to the real numbers. I don't have that information.

Comment: @Deltab, but the very beginning of your post says $x, y \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: x and y in R, doesn't say anything about x+y.

Comment: @Deltab but... the sum of two reals is a real.  That's an axiom.

Comment: Really? Which one? I thought it was an theorem, did you read my question?

Comment: I didn't read your edited Q closely and I only mildly recall this from last year.  It's the closure axiom and it's true of all fields, not just $\Bbb R$.  None of that matters anyway, since my point was that if you *already know* that $x$ is a real number in the equation "$f(x) = 0$", then you can call that real number *whatever you want*, because you're *already working under the assumption* that it's a real number.  "$f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in \Bbb R$" simply means "$f$ gives me back $0$ when I put any real number into it."  The name of that real number is completely irrelevant.

Comment: you're right, but if x+y wasn't a real number then you couldn't do that, right?

Comment: Not with 100% certainty, but that's a non issue if you already know the thing you're calling "$x+y$" is a real number.  If $x$ and $y$ are already referring to something else then you shouldn't use $x+y$ as a name for the real number anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It was hard to understand the question:

But I think the questions are:

1) if you are given that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, prove $f(y) = f(x+y) = 0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Proof:  If $x,y \in \mathbb R$ then $k= x+y \in \mathbb R$ and $f(k) = f(x+y) = 0$.  And $y \in \mathbb R$ so $f(y) =0$. And $0=0$ so $f(y) = f(x+y) = 0$.

2) if you are given that $f(x+y) = 0$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb R$ prove that $f(y) = 0$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$.

Your teacher claims this is not so easy.  It's not much harder.  $0 \in \mathbb R$ and $y + 0 = y$ so $f(y) = f(y+ 0) = 0$.

Comment: You got it kinda backwards, sorry for poorly stating the question, I would start with $f(y)=0,
f (x)=0$ and arrive at $ f (x + y) = 0 $

Comment: What *exactly* are you given and what *exactly* are you trying to prove.  It was very very *very* hard to understand your question.

Comment: Given: $f(y)=0,f(x)=0$ for all reals, Prove: $f(y+x)=0$ for all real.

Comment: That's trivial.  The fact that you can even talk about real numbers or functions imply that one knows *what* the real numbers are.  So one knows x+y is a real number.  That's something done long before the notion of futons was even discussed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then it is completely trivial that $f(x+y)=0$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  Indeed, let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers.  Then $x+y$ is just some real number, and you already know that $f$ of any real number is $0$ (that is the meaning of "$f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$").  Thus $f(x+y)=0$.

Comment: How do I would prove that for $ x, y $ being reals $ x+y $ is also real?

Comment: To prove something like that you would need a precise definition of "real number" and "$+$", and how to prove it would depend a lot on what your definitions are.  In the context of a problem like this, it would almost always be assumed to already be known that the sum of two real numbers is a real number.  (For instance, it doesn't even make sense to write $f(x+y)$ without this, since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: I know the sum of two reals are a real number, I do not know the proof of that, and I wanted to know it.

Comment: You don't prove that x +y is a real number.  You *define* the reals so that it is true.  It's really beyond to scope of your class.  But a field is a system in which .. addition is closed (among other things).  The rational numbers are defined to be be the smallest field that has a less than comparison on it.  The reals are an extension of the rationals so that it is a field but also every "limit" exist.  So x + y is a real by definition.

Comment: @fleablood How much beyond my scope? Real analysis, set theory, group theory?